# How should I create an IPIP tunnel between 2 OpenVPN servers?

Tags: networking, centos, openvpn, tunnel

I have 2 CentOS 7 servers which both of them have OpenVPN installed on them . I want my clients on the first server to be able to connect to the OpenVPN server and then I want their network traffic to be sent to the second OpenVPN server and then from the second OpenVPN server to the internet .

So basically I want my users from the first OpenVPN server to have the IP of second OpenVPN server which would be called a tunnel I guess .

Can anyone point me to the right direction on how to accomplish this and where to start ? Thanks .

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/701302/double-vpn-openvpn) question, which is quite similar...
And, while you are at it, read a bit of introduction about a site-to-site openvpn tunnel [here](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/site-to-site-routing-explained-in-detail/).

I really would think twice if I really would setup a complicated setup like this... if you really need two servers for that task, think of the following setup: Server B has a OpenVPN Server instance running on Port X
Server A only has the following running:

`socat UDP-LISTEN:1194,fork,reuseaddr UDP:serverB:X`

Basically, this command should forward all traffic it receives on udp port 1194 to serverB port X (the openvpn instance). The fork option guarantees that every openvpn client receives its own sourceport and therefore is distinguishable for the server. That way, you'll have an end-to-end encryption without the need to mess with a complicated dual-vpn setup...